# Interrupt Exception in thread Thread-1: and I2C read failed using pigpio

Tags: python, i2c, pigpio, interrupts

im writing a sensor program with python 3 that has a GUI and if the accelerometer detects motions it goes into an interrupt routine and saves and plots the data for a specific timeframe.

Now onto the problem, sometimes when the interrupt routine starts i get an error, sometimes it does not. The error doesnt always stop at the same location, it can stop when it goes into the readACCx/y/z() methods or when it initialises some registers outside of the interrupt routine. Can anyone make sense of the error or what i should do? Thanks already for the help

Here is the error:

```
interrupt 1
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1213, in run
    cb.func(cb.gpio, newLevel, tick)
  File "/home/pi/Masterarbeit/tkinter/mix/mix.py", line 330, in my_callback1
    self.pi.i2c_read_byte_data(self.acc_sensor, FF_MT_SRC)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 2874, in i2c_read_byte_data
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_I2CRB, handle, reg))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1011, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
pigpio.error: 'I2C read failed'
```

Here is my interrupt routine. I know its pretty full but tbh i dont know how to shorten it.

Interrupt routine:

```
def my_callback1(self, gpio, level, tick): #first interrupt function
        print("interrupt 1")
        self.pi.i2c_read_byte_data(self.acc_sensor, FF_MT_SRC)
        print("interrupt cleared")
        print(gpio, level, tick)
        
        self.x_graph = []
        self.y1_graph = []
        self.y2_graph = []
        self.y3_graph = []
        
        a = datetime.datetime.now()
        start_time = time.time()*1000
        while(time.time()*1000-start_time) < self.timeframe:
            try:
                b = datetime.datetime.now()
                delta = b-a
                self.x_graph.append(delta.total_seconds()*1000)
                self.y1_graph.append(self.readACCx())
                self.y2_graph.append(self.readACCy())
                self.y3_graph.append(self.readACCz())
            except pigpio.error as e:
                print("error:", e)
                #time.sleep(1)
        #self.save_data()
        self.plot_data()
```

Comment: In the old days I would have just set a flag in the interrupt routine and then do the work in the main event loop.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. My new code does that but since my code is mostly a gui with tkinter which has its own main loop I tried threading. So I have a thread which constantly checks for a flag and if flag is set the old callback gets executed. Sometimes the error still happens. I will see if I can update the code since I'm on vacation

Comment: @nomadmaker https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2024204#p2024204 I posted my new code there, I can't really effectively update my code on my smartphone. Would really appreciate it if you could check it out

Comment: @NomadMaker have you looked at the code? Did you maybe find something that would be interesting or looks wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know enough about python to say.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway for the fast reply